# Error when deleting from mySQL in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm getting an error I don't understand when sending the parameters to my method, I thought my query was wrong but I did it manually and mySQL did what it had to do. So the problem is in my code but I don't seem to find where, thanks in advance.

```
exports.defav = function(id_user, id_restaurant, callback){

console.log(id_user + " " + id_restaurant); //Just making sure i'm reciving correclt
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    callback(true);
    return;
  }

  connection.query("DELETE FROM favorites WHERE id_user = ? AND id_restaurant = ?", id_user, id_restaurant, function(err, results) {
    console.log("SUCCESS: Removed from fav ");
    connection.release();
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(true);
        return;
      }

      callback(results);
    });
  });
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters should be passed in an array:

```
connection.query("DELETE FROM favorites WHERE id_user = ? AND id_restaurant = ?", [ id_user, id_restaurant ], function(err, results) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Omg, I don't know how i missed that, I have a hundred more queries with them and I miss them Ha! Thanks for the help will mark as correct in 4 mins as I have to wait.